# What is the most efficient way to reference two array columns of different length against each other?

Tags: python, append, enumerate

For context, I have two files:

A file containing multiple instances or measurements for each ID:
Data Table

```
datafiles = sorted(glob.glob('path/**/*.txt', recursive = True))
    +-----+-----+-----+
    | ID  |  x  |  y  |
    +-----+-----+-----+
    | 20  | 2.3 | 4.5 |
    | 20  | 2.9 | 6.5 |
    | 20  | 5.5 | 7.5 |
    | 21  | 5.4 | 5.5 |
    | 21  | 7.8 | 9.5 |
    | etc | etc | etc |
    +-----+-----+-----+
```

And also a reference table for each ID:
Reference Table

```
ref_table = pd.read_csv('path/**/reference_table.csv')
    +-----+-----+--------+--------+
    | ID  | age | gender | status |
    +-----+-----+--------+--------+
    | 20  | 20  | M      | 0      |
    | 21  | 35  | M      | 1      |
    | 22  | 30  | F      | 1      |
    | 23  | 38  | M      | 0      |
    | 24  | 17  | M      | 1      |
    | etc | etc | etc    | etc    |
    +-----+-----+--------+--------+
```

I am trying to find the most efficient way to append the value of 'status' in the Reference Table to the Data Table as a new column with the ID as the key. I have been using a nested for loop to cycle through the two columns and append the 'status' value to an array as follows:

```
    s = []
    for ref_ID, ref_val in enumerate(ref_table):   
        count_a +=1
        count_b +=1
        for data_ID, data_val in enumerate(datafiles):   

            status = reference.iloc[count_a:count_b,3:4]
            status = np.asarray(status)[0]

            if ref_val == data_val:
                s = np.append(s, status)


    count_a = 0
    count_b = 1
```

However, using this method with over 800 ID's and roughly 10,000 instances is very inefficient and is taking much longer than I believe it should. What other methods might I use to speed up this process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.join()` to join the tables on the key `ID`, and then just use `pandas.DataFrame.drop()` to remove the columns you don't want. Like this:

```py
joined = datafiles.join(ref_table.set_index("ID"), on="ID")
joined = joined.drop(columns=["age", "gender"])
```

I ran this on the data you showed in your question as an example:

```
>>> joined
   ID    x    y  status
0  20  2.3  4.5       0
1  20  2.9  6.5       0
2  20  5.5  7.5       0
3  21  5.4  5.5       1
4  21  7.8  9.5       1
```